# Check if node visible to camera in OSG

Tags: opengl, openscenegraph

How can I check if a node in my scene graph is actually seen by my main camera?

In my particular use-case, I want to know if a node is (in the area) behind the camera.

Thanks.

Comment: just behind is easy, just do the dot product between the view direction and the vector from camera to node, if negative then it is behind.

Comment: @ratchetfreak: excellent! How would I do that?? (Sorry!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to know 3 things to do this: the view direction, the position of the camera and the position of the node (all in the same coordinate system).

Then the test is easy: `dot(view, nodePos-cameraPos)<0` where `dot(v1, v2)` is the dot product of 2 vectors in other words `v1.x*v2.x + v1.y*v2.y + v1.z*v2.z`.

Comment: I have `cam->getViewMatrixAsLookAt(eye, center, up)`. And `n = node->getBound()->center()`. Then I do `center * (n - eye)`? Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: `(center-eye)*(n-eye)` actually

Comment: It works, but I have to do something like `(center-eye)*(n-eye) < ε`. If I set it to zero, it doesn't catch all objects (maybe I have a strange setup.) Otherwise it seems to work, so I'll accept this answer. :-)